# Why the zero morphism is independent of the zero object?

Tags: category-theory

I want to know, Why the zero morphism is independent of the zero object. I have $0 \in \mathcal{C}$ the zero object and $0_{X,Y}: X \to 0 \to Y$ the zero morphism. I am very confused to prove that the zero morphism is independent of the zero object. Can anybody give me an idea?

Comment: The zero object is unique up to isomorphism. Why should you care about different zeros then?

Comment: @Dog_69 I know that the zero object is unique up to isomorphism but I don´t know how to use this to prove that is independent

Comment: Use the existence AND unicity of morphisms to (and from - but start with to) $0$, a zero object. So say you have another $0'$, a zero object.  If $f\colon X \to 0$, $f' \colon X \to 0'$, $u\colon 0' \to 0$, then $f = u \circ f'$ - etc... So $g\circ f = g'\circ u^{-1}\circ u \circ f'$ - modulo details... OK?

Comment: @RobArthan you don't like the sketch of 'my' argument?

Comment: @AlejandraBenítez did my hint help, or not at all?

Comment: @peterag I understood the beginning but I don't know what to do after that

Comment: @AlejandraBenítez if I were more on the ball, and knew how, I would start a chat session .... But at one point, the system will get annoyed at us, and start one for us - in the meantime :  in my notation, there is a unique $u\colon 0'\to 0$. There is a unique $f\colon X \to 0$, and unique $f'\colon X\to 0'$. Hence $f = u\circ f'$. Agree?

Comment: @peterag I am agree

Comment: Great. Likewise, there is a unique $v\colon 0 \to 0'$. Since the only morphism $0\to 0$, and $0' \to 0'$ are the identities, we must have that $ u\circ v=1$ and $v\circ u = 1$. That is, $v$ is the $u^{-1}$ I wrote in the hint. Agree?

Comment: @peterag Yes, I understand this part

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109520/discussion-between-peter-a-g-and-alejandra-benitez).